# Unanswered questions showing last editor instead of OP

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

If you visit the [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) for any SE site, you will notice the original question author's name and icon beside the question.

However, if you visit the [list of unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) you will instead see the name and icon for the person who last edited the post.

Is there a justified reason for this? I think it makes more sense to show the OP's name, rather than the last editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd notice, it says "modified" above the image:

[image]

It means that the information is regarding the latest modification (probably because that's how it's listed). I'd call this one [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You shouldn't care about the OP's reputation when answering a question. You don't answer users, you answer questions. It's all about the questions. It's possible for a 1 reputation to ask a much better question than a 40k one. Also, if you need to see the OPs reputation so bad, just enter the question.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I noticed it says "modified" above the image; that's exactly what prompted me to ask this. And I'm not suggesting that you shouldn't answer a question based on a user. My point is: There is a difference between the way 'questions' and 'unanswered questions' are formatted. Why? It's clearly by-design, and that's fine, but an explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though it's worded poorly. Take this question for example:

[image]

`modified` seems to mean there was some sort of activity on this question. In the case of the [above question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592891/is-there-a-library-for-converting-flash-flex-as3-textlayoutformat-data-to-html?answertab=oldest#tab-top), that happened to be the last user who answered the question. There was nothing *modified* in the question.